# Launch PhoneGap-based iPhone app from email link

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, cordova, launching-application

I just switched from Titanium to PhoneGap. All works well except that I have been unable to get the app to be launch-able from an email link. The iPad/iPod animates to start the app and then the app crashes.

In this posting, the real app name has been changed to "myapp". The link I'm using in the email is `myapp://` (i.e., the real app name) usually with an argument (e.g., `myapp://?argument=value`), and `${PRODUCT_NAME}` is the same string as `myapp`.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

---

### PLIST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>    <true/>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>             <true/>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>              <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>            <string>My App</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>             <string>com.mydomain.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>                   <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>            <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>                <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>             <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon.png</string>
                <string>icon_large.png</string>
            </array>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>  <string>6.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageFile~ipad</key>         <string>Default-ipad</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageFile~iphone</key>       <string>Default</string>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>      <string>English</string>
        <key>NSMainNibFile</key>                  <string></string>
        <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>              <true/>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key> <string>com.mydomain.myapp</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>myapp</string>
                        </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

---

### Crash report....

```
Incident Identifier: 973EADC9-716C-4B4E-AD6A-90AC0C169091
CrashReporter Key:   b6522af7d8c20e0bd67387a9296d0b2eed51dbfd
Hardware Model:      iPod3,1
Process:         myapp [3547]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1C530E3F-4441-4CBF-A23E-57D86E7FE91A/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:      myapp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-01-08 21:56:42.506 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d90d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34981a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a83594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497fdf2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497fe46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497ff16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a824c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3587a7c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3587a7fc +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  Foundation                      0x31178972 -[NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 166
13  myapp                           0x00006bd0 +[InvokedUrlCommand newFromUrl:] (InvokedUrlCommand.m:46)
14  myapp                           0x00010658 -[PhoneGapDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (PhoneGapDelegate.m:191)
15  UIKit                           0x341e1bbe -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 766
16  UIKit                           0x341dd252 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 266
17  UIKit                           0x341a9484 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
18  UIKit                           0x341a8ec2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
19  UIKit                           0x341a8900 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
20  GraphicsServices                0x320c8efc PurpleEventCallback + 660
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3580f6f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3580f6bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
23  CoreFoundation                  0x35801f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
24  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
25  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
26  UIKit                           0x341dc302 -[UIApplication _run] + 374
27  UIKit                           0x341d9e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
28  myapp                           0x00002614 main (main.m:14)
29  myapp                           0x00002594 start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d30974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dd9b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e9e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d042c4 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d31b3a semaphore_wait_signal + 2
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d060d0 pthread_mutex_lock + 252
3   WebCore                         0x34b4479c _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 24
4   WebCore                         0x34b44c46 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 14
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3580ac52 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3580aac6 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
7   CoreFoundation                  0x358020d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 860
8   CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
9   CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
10  WebCore                         0x34bf6124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e1192e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3358c989      r6: 0x0012799c      r7: 0x2fdfe154
    r8: 0xffffffff    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0000001f     r11: 0x00117720
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe154      lr: 0x327eb2cb      pc: 0x327eb2d4
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x1ffff +myapp armv7  <f79bcdcc3a0da9f812dbd95b0701ec57> /var/mobile/Applications/1C530E3F-4441-4CBF-A23E-57D86E7FE91A/myapp.app/myapp
   0xb4000 -    0xb5fff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30018000 - 0x3001afff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3018a000 - 0x302aafff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x302c9000 - 0x302cdfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x302d9000 - 0x302e9fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x302ea000 - 0x302f0fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x302f5000 - 0x3058ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x305a4000 - 0x305e4fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x305e5000 - 0x3061cfff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3064b000 - 0x30656fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30659000 - 0x306a6fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x306ba000 - 0x306fdfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3074c000 - 0x307e2fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x307e3000 - 0x30820fff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x321a4000 - 0x321a5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x321c6000 - 0x321ccfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <7e279d3b6d1e1fd7dc8c8a883255fa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x324fd000 - 0x32500fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32501000 - 0x32617fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3274f000 - 0x32756fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32772000 - 0x32883fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3288a000 - 0x32897fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x328e2000 - 0x32911fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32913000 - 0x3298ffff  AVFoundation armv7  <4c7356c795e01bd5c21b00a409a07476> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x32990000 - 0x329a6fff  EAP8021X armv7  <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x329c4000 - 0x32a71fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32ab3000 - 0x32ab3fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32ab4000 - 0x32ab9fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32b4e000 - 0x32c36fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x32c3e000 - 0x32ce7fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x32d08000 - 0x33089fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33090000 - 0x33092fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33218000 - 0x3321dfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x33280000 - 0x332cbfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x333b6000 - 0x333c9fff  MediaControl armv7  <874e83896424ebb3afe59a3a59ba4dfe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x333e5000 - 0x33405fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x33406000 - 0x33409fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a2af7147f5538d7669b14fa7b19b5a7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3346b000 - 0x33474fff  ITSync armv7  <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3354a000 - 0x33594fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3365a000 - 0x33666fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3367d000 - 0x3369cfff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x337e8000 - 0x3381bfff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x338e9000 - 0x33a08fff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33a15000 - 0x33b52fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33b56000 - 0x33b95fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33b99000 - 0x33c47fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33c4a000 - 0x33c53fff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33c85000 - 0x33c9afff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33c9b000 - 0x33c9dfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33ca0000 - 0x33ca1fff  DataMigration armv7  <babbc72d4d48325de147d5103d7bc00d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x33ca2000 - 0x33cb5fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33cb6000 - 0x33da3fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33dc8000 - 0x33df1fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33fa4000 - 0x34013fff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3403e000 - 0x34626fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34629000 - 0x3462cfff  CertUI armv7  <5f37446c6b65a8c38ab6233c2e33da66> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x34636000 - 0x34638fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x34639000 - 0x3464bfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd2a699aa5036bdad0517603ba4db839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34681000 - 0x346b7fff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34a6d000 - 0x34a75fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b29d4c5e300ef81060e38f72bb583c02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34a84000 - 0x34b93fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <9337abd4fdd749473efaefe64ee649a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x34bee000 - 0x34c81fff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34c82000 - 0x34c88fff  IAP armv7  <134f59ad5bb91bab6a5fe21b6f36dc8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34c89000 - 0x34c8cfff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x34c8d000 - 0x34c95fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x34d71000 - 0x34dabfff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34dac000 - 0x34e01fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x34e06000 - 0x34e13fff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34e14000 - 0x34e14fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34e15000 - 0x34ed6fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34f04000 - 0x34fb3fff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34fb4000 - 0x35055fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x3520a000 - 0x35214fff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35223000 - 0x35259fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e19b7aa132318fc90618a663bd576461> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x355d5000 - 0x355d8fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x355f9000 - 0x35732fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3579a000 - 0x35859fff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3589a000 - 0x358dcfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35a0e000 - 0x35af4fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35af5000 - 0x35b45fff  GMM armv7  <2b63c1e1ce647e031a8a491e156f04d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35b92000 - 0x35b9afff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x35b9e000 - 0x35ba5fff  WebUI armv7  <e9fc60d6b8e995168dc82e16b0f226f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x35cdc000 - 0x35cdffff  ArtworkCache armv7  <1e65b5000a2234b69164e7904fcf826b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x35ce4000 - 0x35cf0fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35cf1000 - 0x35d19fff  StoreServices armv7  <f409aaf487bd7e7a08c77ba5a2a83a1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x35e1a000 - 0x35e4bfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35fa3000 - 0x35fd5fff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x360ab000 - 0x360b2fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x360b5000 - 0x360b7fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x36140000 - 0x36232fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <34edbee423aa7e2ea32ad4eed0620b85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
```

Comment: I thought I had this fixed by rebuilding the app from scratch. Unfortunately, all that did was change the symptoms. If the app is already in memory, launching from a link properly starts it -but- it doesn't pass the arguments. If the app is not in memory, clicking the link starts the app, followed by it crashing.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but why the switch from titanium to phonegap, I had thought phonegap was the poorer cousin...

Comment: Obviously whatever string you pass to InvokedUrlCommand is smaller than expected. What does InvokedUrlCommand do? Can you show us that?

Comment: @Chris: You might want to start a topic on this. I will say that I have two Apple-approved apps, both created with Titanium, and yet I saw the light in switching. Check out the frustrations posted on their website and notice the number of open bugs on their lighthouseapp site (over 1200 the last I checked).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I've not done any iPhone development yet, but a crash report is a crash report. Your app is crashing because of a bad argument to the substringWithRange call on the NSCFString class, called from the newFromUrl method. This looks like a PhoneGap issue. A quick search on InvokedUrlCommand yields a bug report about crashes:

http://phonegap.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20116/tickets/71-crash-when-opening-invalid-custom-url

Looks like PhoneGap is pretty particular about the format of the string.

Comment: Thank you. I, too, eventually discovered the bug on their website; but since you went through the effort, and frankly I should have thought of looking there from the outset, it my pleasure to vote for your answer. Thank you for taking the time to investigate.

Comment: @Alan No problem, glad you were able to find your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code at `PhoneGapDelegate.m:191`, that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [comments in InvokedUrlCommand.m](http://ldt.stanford.edu/%7Eeduc39109/yaac/lab3/iphone/Classes/InvokedUrlCommand.m), the expected URL format is:

```
yourscheme://<Class>.<command>/[<arguments>][?<dictionary>]
```

Your URL format (myapp://?argument=value) doesn't seem to meet this criteria.